# Error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')"

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mern, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to retrieve data from MongoDB atlas in Visual Studio Code, but I'm getting this error:

```
Mongo connected
--- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
    at mongoDB (mernapp/backend/db.js:10:59)
    at Object.<anonymous> (mernapp/backend/index.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

This is my db.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoURI = "mongodb+srv://varuag:xyz987@foodly.njjoa4i.mongodb.net/"
const mongoDB = async() => {
    try{
        mongoose.set('strictQuery',false)
        mongoose.connect(mongoURI)
        console.log('Mongo connected')
        const fetched_data = await mongoose.connection.db.collection("food_items");
        fetched_data.find({}, {projection: {}}).toArray(function(err, data){
            if(err) console.log('---', err);
            else console.log(data);
        })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("---", err)
        process.exit();
    }
}
module.exports = mongoDB;
```

And, this is my index.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
const mongoDB = require("./db");
mongoDB();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World");
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`The backend is listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

I tried changing

```
fetched_data.find({})
```

to

```
fetched_data.find({}, {projection: {}})
```

I'm new to this tech so I asked bard and got this as a solution but still not getting any data from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your db.js file on line 8 add `await` as in the following code:

```
await mongoose.connect(mongoURI)
```

What's happening is you are trying to access the raw mongo instance and fetching data before the connection is made.

```
mongoose.connection.db //The mongodb.Db instance, set when the connection is opened
```

Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#Connection.prototype.db

**UPDATE:**

Regarding your comment below the following reference says `toArray()` does not take in any parameters.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#mongodb-method-cursor.toArray

You should change your code to use the following.

```
const data = fetched_data.find({}, {projection: {}}).toArray();
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, this made the error go away, however the data is still not printing. The code is not executing anything in "if else" condition. The problem is now in "fetched_data.find()" part.